# Difference between direct return and return $this

Tags: php

I have a bit confusion about a line of script

what is the difference between

this:

```
function pattern2(){
  return $this->two='2';
}
```

and this:

```
function pattern2(){
  $this->two='2';
  return $this;
}
```

the return statement trip me out. Thank you!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of *huh?*

Comment: You're returning two different things. Try echoing the return value.

Comment: The value of an assignment expression is the assigned value, so the first one returns the string value `2`, whereas the second one returns the object instance itself.

Comment: @kabanus: this is php, not JS

Comment: *"the return statement trip me out."* - Are you smoking anything other than cigarettes here?

Comment: @Funk Getting high on `return` statements is a cheap trip…!

Comment: @deceze LMHO! :-)) yeahhh man ;-)

Comment: This whole thing is trippin' me out.

Comment: @mending3 whoops, I seriously missed that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: i'm smoking this return weed haha

Comment: @CBroe: Could you make a little visualization on it, please?

Comment: @Funk Wait, wait, I got another one: It's a… wait for it… *return trip!*

Comment: @deceze [This is a slight'ly heavier return...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZBlqcbpmxY). ;-) Peace bro. ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard: okay bro. Noted. I will choose over the best one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this` refers to the actual class in question.

So when you return $this, then you can chain calls:

```
<?php

class X
{
   private $var;

   public function setVar($value)
   {
       $this->var = $value;
       return $this;
   }

   public function somethingElse()
   {
        return 'xyz';
   }
}

$x = new X();
echo $x->setVar(5)->somethingElse(); // echoes 'xyz'
```

Comment: so what does return return $this refer to? Could you make a visualization about it. sorry i'm a bit bothering you

Comment: @mending3 $x is your instance of the class X, and $this inside the class methods refers to that instance. setVar returns the object instance itself here, which is the reason you can then continue with `->somethingElse()` in the first place - since setVar returned the object $x refers to, the effect is then the same again as if you had called `$x->somethingElse()` separately . Go read up on the keyword "method chaining" for more info on that principle.

Comment: okay bro. so, the sole purpose for returning $this is to chain methods, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

`return $this->two = '2'` returns the result of the assignment operation; the result of an assignment operation is the assigned value, i.e. `'2'`.

`return $this` returns `$this`.

Comment: Whatever `$this` is.